# iOS UINavigationController left-edge swipe gesture make animation in progress not working

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have an ViewController A and ViewController B, both are in Navigation Stack, B is on the top of the stack.

when some animation is in progress on B, and at the same time, I had a left-edge swipe gesture, but I don't loosen my finger. The animations come to the begin state immediately. No matter how long I release my finger, the animations just continue or to the end state.

I have find this, no matter when I loosen my finger, some of runloop method is called. I think this is because the user interaction (I don't loosen my finger) block runloop update layout.

I have test on iOS 10 and iOS 11, only iOS 10 have this Problem.

So, can I solve this problem, I want the animation not be affected by the user left-edge swipe gesture.

## Update

I have a very simple demo:(a blue view, and animate with it bottom offset constraint to its superView on simulator iPhone SE iOS 10.2)

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
    var bottomOffset: CGFloat
    
    if bottomOffsetConstraint.constant == 270 {
        bottomOffset = 100
    } else {
        bottomOffset = 270
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.bottomOffsetConstraint.constant = bottomOffset
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: What kind of animation do you use?

Comment: @LGP hi LGP, i had tried `UIAnimation` update constraints, and `CABasicAnimation`, but both have the same problem

Comment: @LiMengtian : I dont know do I understand ur issue properly, if your problem is that animation stops on left-edge swipe, then I Belive its a intended behavior, View looses all the animations added to it when its no longer visible, like in your case when you left swipe viewWillDisappear will be called on the view controller there by causing all the animation objects added to its view and subviews to be destroyed. Hence animation stops. If you are using CABasicAnimation, iOS uses GPU to perform animation and not the CPU hence none of your touch can block the animation as u interpreted

Comment: touches are processed by CPU and not the GPU. Hence your GPU is free to continue with animation even if u burden your CPU with some runloop calls. So that cant be the reason for animation to freeze. As far as I know, its the destruction of Animation object that causes animation to freeze, you can use removedOnCompletion to keep the elements in UI wherever they were once animation object destroyed

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Hi, Sandeep Bhandari, thanks for your answser. I had update the question, u can see that ,actually, the animation is not stop or destroyed, it is continue in progress whether or not I release my finger. 
I think you are right, "touches are processed by CPU and not the GPU". 
But it likely a screenshot are above my viewController, do you have a solution to handle this? Thanks again！！！

Comment: @limengtian : I still think its default, do u know any app in which animation continues when your push/ pop animation in progress? I dont know any, as far as I know all the animations are paused if push/pop/any system animations are in progress

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Okay, but in my real project ,I have an inputBar above a presented keyboard, when i have a left-edge drag , the keyboard dismiss normally, but the inputBar does not. (the keyboard animations is not affected)